# How to create javascript library?

Tags: javascript

I want to create simple JavaScript library which will have mostly two functions.
Will just add in header and access those two functions in anywhere in project. I have tried a lots but it did't accessible globally.

Please suggest me help or What structure I need to follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like jquery plugins ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to access all the function outside of the file.